# Basic matrice notation

Tags: matrices, notation

I want to compute the L2 distance between a set of points X and M using matrices, for that I proceed as follows:

1) I substract both matrices, X-M

2) I square each matrice member (X-M)^2

3) I collapse the matrice into a column vector by summing the column values of each row.

I lack some formalization knowledge of matrices, so my questions are, is T^2 the correct way to represent the squaring of each matrice member?
And what's the correct way to represent the operation I'm doing at 3) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if $T$ is a matrix, then $T^2 = T \cdot T$ (matrix multiplication).

What you are doing is the [Hadamard Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_%28matrices%29).

Also, summing the rows of a matrix is equivalant to multiplying the matrix by a column vector of all $1$'s.

Comment: Your right! It works, thanks! :)